# Почему идёт вывод последнего индекса?

Tags: javascript

В общем, возникла одна проблема, есть примерно такой код

```
const list = [{
 name : "Alex"
},
{
 name: "John"
},
{
name : "Jusy"
}]
```

Проблема в том, что я циклом делал пробежку, чтобы выводить по очереди каждое имя

```
for(name of list) {
 console.log(name)
}
```

Но в итоге получал всегда лишь последний index, как мне делать пробег так, чтобы выводилось всё по очереди
к примеру если нужно сделать так:

```
for(name of list) {
 element.innerHTML = name
 reply()
}
```

В чём проблема, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Циклом Вы перебираете объекты в массиве, но надо же и ключ указывать, если нужно конкретное значение:

```js
const list = [
  { name: "Alex" },
  { name: "John" },
  { name: "Jusy" }
]

for (obj of list) {
  console.log(obj.name)
}
```

В цикле по очереди создаются и добавляются параграфы, исходя из перебираемых объектов и найденных ключей и их значений:

```js
const list = [
  { name: "Alex" },
  { name: "John" },
  { name: "Jusy" }
]

for (obj of list) {
  console.log(obj.name);
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<p>${obj.name}</p>`);
}
```

Comment: Он выводит все имена, это хорошо, да, но при выводе куда-либо, он выводит последний, можно как-то  сделать, чтобы выводилось поочерёдно?

Comment: @klausdartant: добавил вариант. Значения не появляются разом, а перечисляются согласно циклу.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуй, друг.

```
const list = [{
 name : "Alex"
},
{
 name: "John"
},
{
name : "Jusy"
}]


for(let name of list) {
 element.innerHTML = name.name
 reply()
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно выводить каждый по очереди, такой код выведет сразу все, если я захочу получить сначала 1,2,3 то выведется последний, можно как-то сделать вывод от 0 до 2? (по индексу 0..1..2)

Comment: Извините, но я не понимаю, что вам надо, по прежнему. Раз 5 перечитал ваш комментарий)
У вас цикл <for>. Внутри него вы можете делать что хотите на каждой итерации.

Comment: @dmitriy_vlz: думаю, что если бы автор правильно сформулировал вопрос, то и задавать бы не пришлось ))